# Как сохранять файлы между приложениями?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть Yii2 advanced приложение. Мне надо сохранить файл из бэкэнда на фронт так что бы он был доступен из обоих приложений... Никак не выходит это сделать. Подскажите как это возможно?

Comment: У вас есть общая папка common, к ней имеют доступ и фронт и бэкенд.

Comment: @AlexMaxTM Но в ней же нету вебрута.

Comment: а зачем вебрут туда? вам же нужно содержимое этого файла менять и читать, вот пусть бекэнд и фронт читают и изменяют этот файл.

Comment: @AlexMaxTM его надо скачивать!!!

Comment: если для скачивания, тогда еще проще можно сделать. Создайте в common каталог docs, а в бэк и фронте в их каталогах web создайте симлинк на  docs. Будет общая папка за закачки и скачивания.

Answer (score 0):

Всего существует несколько вариантов решения подобного вопроса:

1. Худший. Синхронизировать папки: просто копировать файлы из одной папки в другое место. Очевидно худший вариант.
2. Получше. Использовать одну папку в принципе, как правильно сказал `AlexMaxTm`, правда это не всегда применимо.
3. Лучший. Создать символьную ссылку, как опять же правильно посоветовал `AlexMaxTm` при этом физически файлы могут находится хоть в `/mnt/superSecureFlash/` ведь ничего не мешает создать больше двух или трех ссылок. Правда тут стоит помнить что `apache` и `nginx` могут запретить следовать по символьным ссылкам, но это надо смотреть на настройки, как минимум `nginx` по-умолчанию разрешает.